# Is an even number of DRAM chips required?

Tags: memory, microprocessor, nxp, dram

I want to design a microprocessor based board (NXP imx 8m). All the boards I've seen so far have an even number of DRAM chips. If I want 4GB of RAM, do I have to use two 2GB DRAM chips or can I use one 4GB chip?

Comment: x1, x2, or x?, exactly?

Comment: If you are asking *this* question, you are not yet aware of the things you actually need to be concerned about in such a design.  Buy a submodule solution, you're not ready to build one.

Comment: I've seen systems with one chip, and I've seen systems with nine (one for ECC or parity). So, no.

Comment: Look in the processor datasheet the supported RAM chip formats : width, depth, number of channels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of DRAM chips is determined by the width of each chip in bits and the number of bits you need for your memory interface.

In this case you have a 32 bit interface, so provided you had a 32 bit wide LPDDR IC, you could use a single chip.